# How can i stop a event from targeting?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of grids with a class called "grid-show". I want to style this specific element that my mouse is over (without using the .hover property in CSS), but when the mouse is not over, I want it to stop and goes back to normal. The "else if" in my example doesent manage to do that.

```
  let divShow = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-show');

  for(i = 0; i < divShow.length; i++){
    divShow[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(eve){

      if (eve.target) {
        eve.target.style.color = "orange"
      } else if(!eve.target){
        eve.target.style.color = " ";
      }

    })
  }
```

Comment: `eve.target` will always be truthy. But wouldn't CSS's `:hover` be a much more elegant solution?

Comment: Yes it would, however i wanted to do it this way so that i could use it for other purposes later where :hover isnt an option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a CSS based solution would be more elegant, but if you still want to do it programmatically, you could use the "mouseout" event to remove the style:

```js
let divShow = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-show');

for(i = 0; i < divShow.length; i++){
  divShow[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
    event.target.style.color = "orange"
  })

  divShow[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
    event.target.style.color = "";
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the event doesent work any longer when i add grids to the div using this function function: postNote(){
  show1.innerHTML += `
  <div class="grid-show">
  <p >${input1.value}</p>
  </div>
  `;
}

Comment: If you are you adding the `divs` after adding the event listeners then it won't work. You could execute again the function that adds the event listeners every time you add a new `div`, but then, all previous existing `divs` will have duplicated event listeners. You should consider to create the `div` elements using `createElement` and add the event listeners to each one of them before inserting them in the `dom`, or use "event delegation", as KooiInc proposed in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `mouseenter` instead (which only fires when the mouse enters the *targeted container* - it doesn't bubble) and add a separate listener for `mouseout`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.grid-show').forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    div.style.color = 'orange';
  });
  div.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    div.style.removeProperty('color');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="grid-show">foo</div>
<div class="grid-show">bar</div>
```

If you use `mouseover` instead of `mouseenter`, the event will also run whenever the mouse enters a child element, which is (probably) not desirable, eg

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.grid-show').forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    console.log('mouseover handler');
    div.style.color = 'orange';
  });
  div.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    div.style.removeProperty('color');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="grid-show">foo<span>child</span></div>
<div class="grid-show">bar<span>child</span></div>
```

The problem with `if (eve.target) {` is that an `event.target` for a mouse event will always be truthy.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop if you use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", evt => {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.classList && origin.classList.contains("grid-show")) {
    origin.classList.add("hoverColor");
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseout", evt => {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.classList && origin.classList.contains("grid-show")) {
    origin.classList.remove("hoverColor");
  }
});
```

```css
.grid-show {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hoverColor {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-show">div 1</div>
<div class="grid-show">div 2</div>
<div class="grid-show">div 3</div>
<div class="grid-show">div 4</div>
```